# Optionally @staticmethod in classes

Tags: python, static-methods

I would like to know if is possible create a optionally `@staticmethod`, i mean... instances and non-instances could use, something like:

```
class Something:

    @staticmethod
    def something(self, file):
        # if argument is provided, use as static, if not, should be a instance calling..
```

Comment: What about calling the class method from an instance method?

Comment: It's possible, but - what for ?

Comment: Hm, interesting... is there a better practice for such thing?

Comment: Show us your actual use case. Right now it's hard to imagine that this would be a good idea.

Comment: For what thing? We don't know what you're trying to achieve.

Comment: What for? I have this need in this exactly moment.. i have this class that handle firebird connections, and now i just need connect without the need of creating a instance, just to confirm one piece of information..

Comment: If class instance is not required to handle particular task - use static method. If one is definitely required - use "common" object method (with _self_). Mixing two in one is nothing but complicating things (and, the most troublesome, obscuring logic)

Comment: _*args_ is what you're looking for, but I strongly suggest you to split such method in to two for the best

Comment: It sounds like you should just have two methods.

Comment: I'm really new to python, and i'm searching for the best practice for this case, could someone give me a answer with an example?

Answer (score 0):

You can see [this really helpful discussion](https://julien.danjou.info/blog/2013/guide-python-static-class-abstract-methods) on python methods. Summarizing, every method in a python class is a class attribute, so you could:

```
class Something:
    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name

    def something(self=None, file=""):
        if self:
            print(self.name)
        print(file)
```

This would yield the following results:

```
>>> Something.something(file="File")
File
```

And:

```
>>> Something("My").something(file="File")
My
File
```

I'm not sure if this is the best practice, but what you ask for *is* possible. Hope this helps clarify!